# Google Maps on iPhone wont update map orientation as I cycle

Tags: iphone, google-maps

Goole Maps on my iPhone have has stopped changing the orientation of the map in cycling mode.

The first image is a screengrab of Apple's maps. You can see the arrow is the same direction as the direction im going.

The second image is a screengrab of Google Maps. I cant get the map to update as I make turns so that the arrow is the same direction as me. Im talking about how car GPSs always work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see a setting for that like apple maps has.  If the behavior changed with an update send feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap the 'North Up' symbol, then the next view will go back to Head Up.
[I can't check 'live' as I'm sitting at my compy, but that works for static route lists.]

[image]